# Android Constarint Layout ScrollView and Bottom Issue Landscape

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

[image: Landscape]

I am using constraint layout for my page and it is working good if it in portrait  but views are overlapping when it is landscape mode. I have added scroll view also , but still it is overlapping only.I need the card view should be present in the bottom and in landscape mode it should be visible while scrolling... I know  the issue is because of that card view (cv_items).I don't know how to fix this issue.

Here is my xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cv_item">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                style="@style/semiBoldTextInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:text="@string/you_got_req"
                android:textColor="@color/light3"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_center"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light3"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_150sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:contentPadding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_accept"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="#555555"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_150sdp">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        style="@style/semiBoldTextInput"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/accept"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </ScrollView>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/_200sdp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_order_number"
                style="@style/semiBoldTextInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="#123456789" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_no_of_items"
                style="@style/regularTextInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_order_number"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                tools:text="6" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_items"
                style="@style/regularTextInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_order_number"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_no_of_items"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_no_of_items"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/items"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"

                />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_price"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_amount"
                        style="@style/semiBoldTextInput"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                        tools:text="1233 RS" />


                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_half"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_items"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="@color/light4" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_items"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                tools:itemCount="20"
                tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_test_details" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please refer the screenshots.

[image: Portarit]

Answer (score 0):

Try to put everything inside `ScrollView`. Check below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cv_item">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                style="@style/semiBoldTextInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:text="@string/you_got_req"
                android:textColor="@color/light3"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_center"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light3"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_150sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:contentPadding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_accept"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="#555555"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_150sdp">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        style="@style/semiBoldTextInput"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/accept"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/_200sdp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_order_number"
                    style="@style/semiBoldTextInput"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="#123456789" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_no_of_items"
                    style="@style/regularTextInput"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_order_number"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    tools:text="6" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_items"
                    style="@style/regularTextInput"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_order_number"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_no_of_items"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_no_of_items"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/items"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"

                    />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_price"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_amount"
                            style="@style/semiBoldTextInput"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                            tools:text="1233 RS" />


                    </RelativeLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_half"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_items"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@color/light4" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_items"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    tools:itemCount="20"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_test_details" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```